# Typescript filter returning an empty array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filtering

I have a filtering function in Angular that is returning an empty array. I know there similar questions have been asked before, and i have tried all of them, but have failed. The function itself seems correct. Any help would be appreciated.

gifts is an array of gift objects (see below)

Typescript:

```
export class DetailsPageComponent implements OnInit {

  
  gifts: Array<Gift> = [ ... ]
  id: number
  currentGift: any

  constructor(private currentRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.currentRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.id = +params.get('id')
      
      this.currentGift = this.gifts.filter(gift => {
        gift.id == this.id
      })
    })
  }

}
```

A gift object:

```
{
name: 'giftName',
id: 22,
}
```

**UPDATE** Changing *gift.id == this.id*  **to**  *gift.id == 22* did return a value. Which means that this.id is not being fetched properly. Not sure why... Any ideas?

Comment: Are you adding the id to the url?

Comment: Yes i am. It is using the i of the gift that is clicked in another component, and is used as a route param. On routing to this component the correct id is show in the searchbar as "localhost:4200/details-page/:11"

Comment: have you tried localhost:4200/details-page/11 (no semi-colon)?

Comment: "localhost:4200/details-page/:11"  no, that's not correct. It will set `params.get('id')` to `':11'` and this string obviously can't be converted to a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter function

```
this.currentGift = this.gifts.filter(gift => {
    gift.id == this.id
})
```

doesn't return anything. It has to return a boolean value:

```
this.currentGift = this.gifts.filter(gift => gift.id === this.id)
```

Here is an example:

```js
const gifts = [{
    name: 'giftName',
    id: 22,
}];

const id = +'22';

const currentGift = gifts.filter(gift => gift.id === id);

console.log(currentGift);
```

You have to use a URL like `localhost:4200/details-page/11` instead of `localhost:4200/details-page/:11` otherwise `params.get('id')` will be set to `':11'` and this string obviously can't be converted to a number.

Comment: Still returning an empty array. i think it is an issue with the ID. It is showing this.id as an Nan.

Comment: @SarmadHadi I added an example assuming that `params.get('id')` returns a valid number as string. If it doesn't work you have another problem somewhere else in code you didn't provide. You could check it with `console.log(params.get('id'))`.

Comment: Yeah that's what i think.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot. I was confused as i had to keep it :id in the router module and plain id in therest of the places.